# Site Page Logo will not update from default

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, master-page, site-collection, site-logo

I have been working on a page and I had set it up to inherit from the parent, however when the page displays in the browser you can quickly view the new logo then the page reverts to the SharePoint logo. I have been looking in designer where to update this and I had gone to the v4master (backup) to update this change. Now the page is updated in the designer, but still not in the browser. It appears that there is some over ridding taking place and I can't quite put my finger on where this is happening. I don't really want to mess with the master pages if I don't need to, but am willing to try just about anything to get this FINALLY working. This is the last thing for this page then it's up and running.

Site Actions-> Site Settings-> Look and Feel-> Title, Description, and icon has been updated with the path where the logo is saved.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are hitting a cache issue so try hitting ctrl-F5 in the browser.  If that doesn't work, make sure that the new logo image is properly checked in and published (assuming it is in the SharePoint site and not in /_layouts/).  If all else fails, rename your image to something you have not called it yet, upload it and configure the page to use the new name.  That will bypass *almost* all caching.

Comment: I learned the default logo is in /_layouts/, but my permissions are limited thus not allowing me to get to them. Thankfully I recreated the same logo so when the page does refresh it does not look like anything changed ;).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Site Page having Different Title Bar Properties, so you update logo or Title in Site Page Properties.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was opening the Designer and at the title bar (because that was not working on the non - designer area) and double clicked the title bar area until a white box appeared asking for the title, description and url for image. That seemed to work :)